# Is there a mistake in FeathersJS generator?

Tags: typescript, mongoose, feathersjs

When generating a service with feathersjs, the model file looks like this

```
import { Application } from '../declarations';

export default function (app: Application) {
  const modelName = 'comments';
  const mongooseClient = app.get('mongooseClient');
  const { Schema } = mongooseClient;
  const schema = new Schema({
    text: { type: String, required: true }
  }, {
    timestamps: true
  });

  // This is necessary to avoid model compilation errors in watch mode
  // see https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/connection.html#connection_Connection-deleteModel
  if (mongooseClient.modelNames().includes(modelName)) {
    mongooseClient.deleteModel(modelName);
  }
  return mongooseClient.model(modelName, schema);
}
```

The mongooseClient is of type `Mongoose` and the documentation says deleteModel is under the `Connection.prototype.deleteModel()`

Shouldn't the line say `mongooseClient.connection.deleteModel(modelName);` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it shouldn't

If you look at the file `mongoose.js` under root folder you can see `'mongooseClient'` is setting after `mongoose.connect` :

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

    module.exports = function (app) {
      mongoose.connect(
        app.get('mongodb'),
        { useCreateIndex: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }
      );
      mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
    
      app.set('mongooseClient', mongoose);
    };
```

So it is part of `Connection.prototype`.